# Best Option for integer validation: intval() or filter_input() or casting int's

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I want to make sure an `int` value is cleaned up and validated before using in a `MySQL` query.

This project does not use prepared statements and as I realize that this is the best option, I am specifically asking about casting `int`, `intval()` and `filter_input()`.

If I have this coming in `$_POST['user_id']`.

```
$user_id = (int) $_POST['user_id'];
$user_id = intval($_POST['user_id');
$user_id = (int) filter_input(INPUT_POST, "user_id", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); 
$user_id = intval(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "user_id", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
```

Which one of these are the best options to use? to make sure I am using an integer, it is validated -- and if it fails it will just return a 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to use `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`

EDIT: with the option `min_range` of `1` assuming you are using an `AUTO_INCREMENT` value for `user_id` in your database

```
if($user_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'user_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 1)){ 
    //success
}
```

This validates it is an integer and then returns a cleaned variable if validation passes.

Comment: negative number will bypass the validation...unless negative number is acceptable

Comment: @Andrew I have updated my answer using the `min_range` option for the filter

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
$user_id = ctype_digit($_POST["user_id"]) ? (int)$_POST["user_id"] : 0;

$test = "123"; // 123
$test1 = "0123"; // 123
$test2 = "-123"; // 0
$test3 = "+123"; // 0
$test4 = "false"; // 0
$test5 = "null"; // 0
$test6 = "asd23"; // 0
$test6 = "23asd"; // 0
$test6 = "+123asd23"; // 0
```